# Firebase with Likes in HTML

Tags: html, ajax, firebase

I need help about how to link likes with Firebase and show real time count? How should I connect this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data with HTML page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .like-content {
         display: inline-block;
         width: 100%;
         margin: 40px 0 0;
         padding: 40px 0 0;
         font-size: 18px;
         border-top: 10px dashed #eee;
         text-align: center;
         }
         .like-content span {
         color: #9d9da4;
         font-family: monospace;
         }
         .like-content .btn-secondary {
         display: block;
         margin: 40px auto 0px;
         text-align: center;
         background: #ed2553;
         border-radius: 3px;
         box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -8px rgb(240, 75, 113);
         padding: 10px 17px;
         font-size: 18px;
         cursor: pointer;
         border: none;
         outline: none;
         color: #ffffff;
         text-decoration: none;
         -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
         transition: 0.3s ease;
         }
         .like-content .btn-secondary:hover {
         transform: translateY(-3px);
         }
         .like-content .btn-secondary .fa {
         margin-right: 5px;
         }
         .animate-like {
         animation-name: likeAnimation;
         animation-iteration-count: 1;
         animation-fill-mode: forwards;
         animation-duration: 0.65s;
         }
         @keyframes likeAnimation {
         0%   { transform: scale(30); }
         100% { transform: scale(1); }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="like-content">
         <button class="btn-secondary like-review">
         <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Like
         </button>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is my basic code for Like HTML Page with like button. The event should happen on click. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In short storing and fetching the lives from Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the data is like :

```
posts
  -post1
     -likes
     -caption
     -id
     -photoLink
  -post2
     -likes
     -caption
     -id
     -photoLink
```

The JS code looks like:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts');
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key; //holds id like posts1,posts2
    var childData = childSnapshot.val(); //holds rest of data in object format
    displayPosts(childData);
  });
});
function displayPosts(childData)
{
    var bodyCode='<div class="like-content">
         <button class="btn-secondary like-review">
         <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true">'+childData.likes+'</i> Like
         </button>
      </div>';
    document.getElementById("post-conatainer").appendChild(bodyCode);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .like-content {
         display: inline-block;
         width: 100%;
         margin: 40px 0 0;
         padding: 40px 0 0;
         font-size: 18px;
         border-top: 10px dashed #eee;
         text-align: center;
         }
         .like-content span {
         color: #9d9da4;
         font-family: monospace;
         }
         .like-content .btn-secondary {
         display: block;
         margin: 40px auto 0px;
         text-align: center;
         background: #ed2553;
         border-radius: 3px;
         box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -8px rgb(240, 75, 113);
         padding: 10px 17px;
         font-size: 18px;
         cursor: pointer;
         border: none;
         outline: none;
         color: #ffffff;
         text-decoration: none;
         -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
         transition: 0.3s ease;
         }
         .like-content .btn-secondary:hover {
         transform: translateY(-3px);
         }
         .like-content .btn-secondary .fa {
         margin-right: 5px;
         }
         .animate-like {
         animation-name: likeAnimation;
         animation-iteration-count: 1;
         animation-fill-mode: forwards;
         animation-duration: 0.65s;
         }
         @keyframes likeAnimation {
         0%   { transform: scale(30); }
         100% { transform: scale(1); }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="post-container">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot help. I am getting 2 errors for this code can you please resolve them. Cannot read property 'likes' of undefined and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
Sequence of the code is Div followed by the scripts